# JSON format list of names - Symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

I'm trying to read a json file and parse it to an array, and then acces that array.

This is my JSON file:

```
{
    "stijn",
    "bert",
    "tom"
}
```

This is how I try to acces it and convert it to an array:

```
$string = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/first.json");
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

if I do a var_dump of $array I get "null", if I do it of $string I get the contents of the JSON file.

I think that my JSON file is not properly formatted, but if I search for some examples they are not suitable for my list of names.

Comment: Try using square brackets for the JSON array. So [ 'stijn', ...].

Comment: Good way to test your json is via http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right, your json is not formatted properly.  you need to show that it is an array, so like this:

```
{
    names: [
        "stijn",
        "bert",
        "tom"
    ]
}
```

OR

```
[
    "stijn",
    "bert",
    "tom"
]
```

notice that square brackets are used for an array.  if you use the curly braces, it's looking for a key/value pair

Comment: I will accept this answer within a few minutes, this one has worked and provided me with some extra helpfull information about json, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
[
    "stijn",
    "bert",
    "tom"
]
```